# JSF Primefaces row value null in Edit popup window

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.0 with Primefaces 3.4.2

For some strange reason I am not able to get the value in popup dialog window when a command button of row in datatable is clicked. Not sure what am I doing wrong?

Any help is highly appreciable.

I have the following in JSF page

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="emp" lazy="true"
   value="#{myMB.lazyModel}" 
selection="#{myMB.selectedEmployee}"...>

<p:column>
<p:commandButton id="edit" update=":frmedit:editDlg" process="@this"
onmousedown="dlg.show()" icon="ui-icon-pencil"
title="Edit" >
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{emp}"
target="#{myMB.selectedEmployee}" />
</p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

Dialog code

```
<h:form id="frmedit">
<p:dialog header="Employees" style="font-weight:bold"
widgetVar=Dialog" resizable="false" id="dlg"
showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" appendToBody="true"
modal="true" width="200" height="250">

<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="5">
<h:outputText value="Employee #" />
<h:outputText value="#{myMB.selectedEmployee.empNo}"
style="font-weight:bold" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

And finally in ManagedBean

```
@Named("myMB")
@ViewAccessScoped

private Employee selectedEmployee= new Employee();
```

with getters and setters

**Update 1**

```
<p:column>                          
<p:commandButton id="edit" update=":frmedit:display" process="@this"
title="View" 
icon="ui-icon-pencil"   style="border-width:0;background:none;"
onmousedown="Dialog.show()">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{emp}"
target="#{myMB.selectedEmployee}" />
</p:commandButton>
</p:column>    


<p:dialog header="Employees" style="font-weight:bold"
widgetVar=Dialog" resizable="false" id="dlg"
showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" appendToBody="true"
modal="true" width="200" height="250">
<h:form id="frmedit">

<h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellspacing="5">
<h:outputText value="Employee #" />
<h:outputText value="#{myMB.selectedEmployee.empNo}"
style="font-weight:bold" />
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Try to user oncomplete="Dialog.show()" in place onmousedown="dlg.show()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three main reasons why this would be the case are

1. The dialog was not actually ajax updated
2. The property listener didn't set the value. You could easily debug this by adding some logging to the setter for that property
3. The bean was actually recreated and the `selectedEmployee` property was re-initialized per your 
   line:

   ```
   Employee selectedEmployee= new Employee();
   ```
4. Per your comments on the previous answer, you should not have `widgetVar` and `id` for the same dialog having the same value

My vote is on (3). You should verify that the bean is not actually being trashed and recreated (constructor or `@PostConstructor` logging).

Comment: kolossus I will try your suggestions and will come back to you.

Comment: kolossus I was go through your suggestions. For point # 2 I put a log in set method of `selectedEmployee` and log statement did not print. Besides when I checked browser console, there is no communication to server when I clicked Edit button. Is that because it is firing ajax method?

Comment: @Polppan You might need to post more of your xhtml here. I suspect your `<h:form/>`s are not well placed. Take your dialog for example, the `<h:form/>` is enclosing your dialog; that's a major no-no when using dialogs

Comment: kolossus I had put enclosed dialog with `<h:form>` and I have removed that put `<h:form>` inside dialog. I have added mmy modified code in my question as Update 1.  Now I am able to get the selected row values in popup window, however I do have one small issue i.e. I am always getting the first row values for all subsequent rows when I click view button. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: kolossus Finally I have managed to get this working. I am not sure whether this is a bug or not, after your suggestion of putting `<h:form>` inside dialog, it was not working correctly. So I have changed from `onmousedown` to `oncomplete` and it started to work perfectly. Thanks for your help, appreciated.

Comment: @Polppan, that's probably my fault: I should've also recommended `appendToBody="true"` so that your dialog doesn't wind up within the HTML body, which already has it's own `<h:form/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try `widgetVar="dlg"` instead, in `<p:dialog...>` , according to this [Example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogForm.jsf) you should call

`dialog` from its `widgetVar` attribute

so `dlg.show()` refers to `widgetVar="dlg"` not the `id`

Comment: I changed to refer to widgetVar, however this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Polppan: try this `update("ElementID")` instead of `update(:frmedit:editDlg)` also for make sure give `widgetVar` and `id` two different value